# How to know what is wrong in a JSON object?

Tags: json

I am trying to send the following JSON object and I get the error shown below,I checked @http://jsonviewer.stack.hu ,the JSON format seems to be correct,what am I missing and how to fix this?

```
{"component":{"name":"Company tech (New Bugs)", "version":"B"},"assignee":1234456,"milestone":"chiHW","priority":2,"state":"Analyze","substate":"Nominate","title":"[please ignore]CS\:4355C1\,4364B2\:WDI\:DHD\:HLK\(16299\)\-\>\"DF\ \-\ Sleep\ Tests\"\-\>Assert\-\>bcmpciedhd63\.sys\(dhd\_os\_ioctl\_resp\_wait\)\-\>dhd\_ndis\.c\@4449"}
```

Error:-

```
{"message":"An invalid JSON Object was passed in the request body. Please pass a valid JSON object.","help":"View documentation at http://bugs.company.com/","title":"Invalid Request","status":"400 Bad Request"}
```

Comment: The problem is those backslashes in your "please ignore" expression. What are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

You could have pasted your expression into https://jsonlint.com. It tells you where the problem is, and you can experiment until the JSON is no longer invalid. In your case, the problem is those backslashes in the last dictionary value (the one that starts "please ignore").

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to get a more specific parse error

```
watson:~$ cat >j
{"component":{"name":"Company tech (New Bugs)", "version":"B"},"assignee":1234456,"milestone":"chiHW","priority":2,"state":"Analyze","substate":"Nominate","title":"[please ignore]CS\:4355C1\,4364B2\:WDI\:DHD\:HLK\(16299\)\-\>\"DF\ \-\ Sleep\ Tests\"\-\>Assert\-\>bcmpciedhd63\.sys\(dhd\_os\_ioctl\_resp\_wait\)\-\>dhd\_ndis\.c\@4449"}
^D


watson:~$ jq <j 
parse error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 333
```